# Is there a simple database app builder that allows for single row access based on token in the row?

Tags: data-transfer, web-services, authentication

I'm currently using thingsboard to manage and deliver IoT device configuration.  The IoT device can access its own configuration with its own auth key.  This is great. However, thingsboard is a quite a lot more than I need and the settings management is bit clunky.  Does anyone know of an db builder that will allow me to set a per row access token that each IoT device can use to fetch it's own row of config data ?  I've looking at budibuilder and airtable but I can't see to get them to allow the IoT devices access to their record.

Update : I've got a bare bones Anvil app that is kinda of working but creating the entire editing interface a serious pain.  All of these other database application designers have all the editing built in but how do get them to serve individual iot device config data without authentication ?

Comment: when you are talking about a database, then the term is `record`, not `row` ..... almost all database programs have a way of retrieving a single record

Answer (score 1):

I know very little about thingsboard, but I would have assumed that if you add an enrichment node to add whatever device attributes you need, you can then use that in a transformation node, to run any javascript you want, where you could access some database such as airtable or even AWS dynamodb and use some of those device attributes as keys.

If you're not on thingsboard but on AWS IoT, you could then use a rule action to access a dynamodb database to get a record, using the client ID (perhaps with other things) as key.

Comment: I really appreciate your answer here but it sounds way too complicated.